# Android: Crashes from unknown phones while internal testing on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, crashlytics

I've implemented Fabric (Crashlytics) in my app. Since yesterday I started an internal test on the Play Store. I created a new APK with a new version number. Only two people have been added to this internal test (which includes myself and a coworker). This morning I got some crashes from Fabric. But these crashes are from unknown phones: A rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 on Android 4.4.2 and a Samsung Galaxy J7 on Android 6.0.1. Where are these crashes coming from?

**Edit**

Internal testing on the Play Store is new. It is like Beta or Alpha builds (so only available for testers added to it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is from [Google's pre-launch report](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270). 
When you upload an APK to an alpha, beta or testing track Google automatically runs your app on a number of devices to test quality.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know they did that. Thanks for the link and explanation!

Comment: Phew! I just had an hour of scary. I can breathe again now :)

Answer (score 0):

We've experienced this on multiple projects too.

We assume that some third party stores, like [apkpure](https://apkpure.com/), grabbed our apks from the playstore to list them in their store.

So those logs will either be from their internal testing devices, or from users that installed the app from the third party store.

We've found that all of our apps that have mysterious logs from unknown rooted devices are listed in one ore more third party stores.

But again, this is only an assumption.

Comment: Yeah that would make sense if the app is live, but since this is an internal testing (this is new, it is like beta and alpha but meant only for internal testing), this app should not available anywhere but only for me and my coworker.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that. Maybe Google runs a test device farm for those internal test projects where uploaded apks will be installed and executed?

Comment: No problem. Yeah that could be true. Seems like they should be the only ones who can access the app besides me and my coworker. I just wasn't expecting it. Can you change your answer? I'll wait a few hours to see if somebody has more insight in this, but else this comment should be an accepted answer